# Successfully pushed to GitHub, but no record on it

Tags: git

After I pushed my local repo to GitHub, it shows success but I couldn't find commit history on it. I'm sure there is a commit log on my local repo.

- My git status.
  `$ git status
  On branch master
  Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.`
- And when I try to push again
  `$ git push
  Everything up-to-date`

Is it possible that this occurs because I used "git push -f" command to restore a commit right before this push? The prior force push succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the remote name and branch name when  pushing to a remote repo.

```
git push <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
```

If you didn't set those names yourself the default is:

```
git push origin master
```

See github's article "[Pushing to a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/)"

To see a logs of the commits on your local machine to compare to your repo you can also type:

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

In case you're not sure what the remote names are you can type the following to see a list of the remotes you have configured:

```
git remote
```

You might want to check the urls of your remotes to make sure they match up with your intended repo by passing a -v flag to the above like so:

```
git remote -v
```

See "[Git Basics - Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)"

Comment: Perhaps point out in more detail that the OP might have overridden the default and so the `git push` actually pushes somewhere else than they expect.

Comment: I also tried the  'git remote remove origin' command, and push my local repo with github url again, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The most basic and powerful command to do this is `git log`

When you run `git log` in your project.

```
$ git log
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Bhanu Prakash <bhanuprakash@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 23 10:42:11 2018 -0700

    changed the version number

commit 085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
Author: Bhanu Prakash <bhanuprakash@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 23 10:42:14 2018 -0700

    removed unnecessary test

commit a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6
Author: Bhanu Prakash <bhanuprakash@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 23 10:42:15 2018 -0700

    first commit
```

By default, with no arguments, `git log` lists the commits made in that repository in reverse chronological order — that is, the most recent commits show up first.